# Integral change of variable simple case proof

Tags: integration

Let $h(x)=cx+n$ with $c>0$. Defining $g(x)=cf(h(x))$.
Q: Prove that $$\int^b_a f (x)dx=\int^{h^{-1}(b)}_{h^{-1}(a)} g(x)dx  $$

How can I prove it?

Comment: edited: c instead of m.

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but doesn't it follow immediately from the Riemann sum definition of the integral?

Comment: yes -- same Riemann sums..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (evaluation version) for both sides or  simply write

the Riemann sum for both integrals and establish a correspondence..

---

The setting is :

[Let $ cA+n=a$ and $cB+n =b$ and P a partition of $[a,b]$ with $ a=x_0<x_1<x_2 ...<x_k=b$ and

the corresponding partition D of [A,B]  is $A=X_0<X_1<X_2...<X_K=B$ where $h(X_i)=x_i$.]

$I=\int_a^b f(x) dx $ means that $\forall $$\varepsilon >0 $  $\exists \delta$ such that $\Vert P \Vert<\delta $ implies |$\sum _{i=1}^k f(x^*_i)\Delta x_i -I|<\varepsilon$ .

So we can use this information to state the following :

$\Vert D \Vert < \delta/c$ implies |$\sum _{i=1}^k  c f(h(X^*_i))  \Delta X_i -I|=|\sum _{i=1}^k f(x^*_i)\Delta x_i -I|<\varepsilon $ (using $c . \Delta X_i=\Delta x_i$)

But this assures us that $\int_A^B cf(h(x)) dx=I $  , too.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the way with Riemann sums?

Comment: i tried to explain above ..